# Symfony - Easy Admin Bundle configuration

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I read the Bundle documentation, but I can't find how to change these labels:

[image: more details]

So, I found how to change the list.page_title, but I can't find about point 1, 2, 4, 5 on the image. Also, I can't find how to remove the ID column (field) from any list view. I follow the tutorial, but when he install Easy Admin Bundle `action.search` was Search for him, action.new was New etc...

I tried with:

```
list:
    fields:
        - '-id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable symfony translation module in your config.yml:

```
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
```

Comment: Yeah this is correct answer, but do u know, how to change it now ?